# Iterar um lista dentro de switch

Tags: python, switch

bom galera eu gostaria de saber como eu faco para iterar uma lista em um `switch` em `python`, tipo eu tenho uma lista com dez valores `lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11]` agora eu quero acessar essa lista valor por valor e criar um laco condicional para cada valor como e que eu faco? agradeco a ajuda de vocês

Comment: Oque é um "laço condicional para cada valor"?

Comment: Python não tem a cosntrução `switch` - vocẽ deve usar  `if` e  `elif`

Comment: tipo eu quero ler cada valor da minha lista eg se o valor for 1 eu executo uma funcao, agora se for 2 eu executo outra funcao acho que e isso

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**update 2021**: Na versão 3.10 do Python está sendo introduzida a construção `match/case`, que também pode funcionar como o `switch/case` do C, embora não seja o objetivo principal. Confira em: [Como funciona o pattern matching estrutural (declaração match) em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/497534/como-funciona-o-pattern-matching-estrutural-declara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-match-em-python/497607#497607)

**Resposta original**

Python não tem uma construção com o nome de `switch` (e o complementar  `case`) - pelo simples motivo de que a forma como o `if` (e os complementares `elif` e `else`)  podem fazer o mesmo trabalho - com algumas vantagens.

Mesmo em linguagens que derivam a sintaxe de C, que tem o `switch`, hoje em dia ele é apenas "mais um jeito de fazer a mesma coisa" - que seria factível com encadeamento de `if` e `else if`s. O motivo histórico de existir uma construção separada é que no tempo em que computadores  tinham muito menos recursos do que hoje (da ordem de 1 milhão de vezes menos memória) - o switch-case era uma forma do programador explicitar para o compilador C uma "tabela de saltos" que geralmente seria mais eficiente do que uma sequẽncia de `if`s quando transformada em código nativo. Já há algumas décadas que os compiladores (e mesmo as CPUs)  incorporaram estratégias de otmização o suficiente para tornar isso redundante.

Mas, voltando ao Python, o jeito mais simples e direto de fazer o que vocẽ quer é simplesmente:

```
for elemento in lista:
    if elemento == 1:
        funcao1()
    elif elemento == 2:
        funcao2()
    ...
    else:
        funcao_nao_encontrado()
```

Perceba que ao contrário do que acontece com o `switch` em qualquer linguagem, a expressão de "verdeiro ou falso" da sequẽncia de if's não está limitada a comparar igualdades - vocẽ pode fazer qualquer comparação, chamar outras funções, etc... - como o Python tem a notação de atalho de comparação de intervalos - a mesma que usamos em matemática - que traduz `a <  x  < b` para `a < x and x < b` - você pode facilmente incorporar intervalos nas suas comparações:

```
    ...
    elif 2 <= elemento < 5:
        funcao_para_numeros_medios()
    elif elemento == 5:
    ...
```

Se parecer que escrever as comparações dos `if` é muita coisa, - se tudo o que você deseja fazer para cada opção é chamar uma função separada, é possível usar a vantagem de que funções em Python são objetos que podem ser passados como parâmetros e usados em outras estruturas de dados - nesse caso, você pode simplesmente criar um dicionário onde as chaves são os números que você colocaria no `case` e os valoes as funções que deseja chamar:

```
def funcao1():
    ...
def funcao2();
    ...
...
funcoes = {
1: funcao1,
2: funcao2,
...
} 

for elemento in lista:
    funcoes[elemento] ()
```

Pronto - essa última linha chama  a função apropriada, que foi recuperada de dentro do dicionário que eu chamei de `funcoes` acima.

Comment: caraca mlk essa eu nao, sabia aprende mais uma agora se eu quiser passar algum argumento na funcao como e que eu faco? +1

Comment: Usando o esquema de dicionários? Se o argumento for fixo, você pode usar o objeto retornado por uma chamada a `functools.partial` para montar seu dicionário de funções: `from functools import partial; funcoes =  {1: partial(funcao_numerica, 1), ...} ;...; elemento=1; funcoes[elemento]()` por exemplo, vai chamar a `funcao_numerica` passando o parâmetro "1" - que vai ser "congelado" quando você fizer a chamada a `partial`.

Answer (score 0):

Python não tem uma função `switch` pelo que eu saiba, se isso for crucial para o programa você pode usar esse pacote: (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/switch/1.1.0) que é similar às linguagens C, C++, Java, etc... Mas com pequenas diferenças.

Edit: como eu não pensei nisso enquanto eu lia? Você também pode (aparentemente) implementar C e C++ em Python (https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)