# Como funciona o pattern matching estrutural (declaração match) em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, característica-linguagem, pattern-matching

Recentemente, o *pattern matching* estrutural foi introduzido versão [3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching) do Python. Para isso, foram introduzidas as palavras-chave `match` e `case`.

Foram, nas notas de *release*, incluídos vários exemplos, entre os quais posso citar:

```
def http_error(status):
    match status:
        case 400:
            return "Bad request"
        case 404:
            return "Not found"
        case 418:
            return "I'm a teapot"
        case _:
            return "Something's wrong with the Internet"
```

Dito isso, pergunto:

- Como funciona o `match` em Python?
- É exaustivo? O que ocorre se o valor a ser consultado não dê *match* em nenhum braço?
- Ele permite o desempacotamento de valores?
- Historicamente, o `switch` [não existe em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127104/69296), mas agora é possível dizer que essa estrutura consta na linguagem? Ou são coisas diferentes?

Comment: Meu amigo, dando uma olhada nessa PEP https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/ você entenderá que Pattern matching é algo mais amplo que o próprio switch originalmente do C (por exemplo) claro, porque as linguagens e os recurso evoluem obviamente. Neste caso do Python, é citado claramente que o recurso sintaticamente semelhante em Scala e Erlang (e outros...). Dá uma olhada também nessa pergunta minha que fiz sobre o Swift muito parecida com a sua! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137912/switch-case-muito-interessante-em-swift-quais-outras-linguagem-suportam-isso

Comment: A sintaxe é esta mesmo? Logo Python que se diz expressiva? Se as pessoas são coerentes logo todo mundo do Python vai pro C#. Ou seja, Python querendo virar PHP, colocando coisas sem pensar, sem atender sua própria filosofia.

Comment: @LuizFelipe me perdoe, não quis passar a ideia que vc não sabia o que era Pattern Match (na pressa escrevi sem tomar esse cuidado). Achei legal a implementação dos protocolos na PEP 0622, veja que massa: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#custom-matching-protocol

Comment: @Maniero (leve na brincadeira o que vou escrever hein... promete?) Não é porque sua única ferramenta é um martelo que todos os seus problemas parecem pregos hehehehe. Se quiser continuar soltando parafusos em Python com talhadeira hahahaha siga em frente. Muito bem-vindo o recurso.

Comment: @Mateus A ideia do [pt.so] é criar um repositório de conhecimento sobre programação, e por isso é comum (quer dizer, hoje em dia nem tanto, mas de qq forma é permitido/encorajado) que as pessoas façam perguntas sobre um assunto que elas já conhecem, para que este conhecimento fique no site, acessível a todos. Claro que a maioria das perguntas acaba sendo feita por quem não conhece o assunto, mas não tem problema nenhum se a pessoa já conhecer

Comment: (só ressaltando que os comentários acima mencionam a PEP 622: ela foi a primeira proposta, mas não foi  a implementada. A sintaxe e exemplos descritos nas PEP 634 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/), 635  e 636 é que valem)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O *pattern matching* não é o mesmo que um `switch`. No código de exemplo que está na pergunta, ele pode até se parecer, mas se entrarmos nos detalhes, veremos que é bem diferente.

Segundo a [PEP 635](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635), o que o *pattern matching* faz é: "*builds a generalized concept of iterable unpacking. **Binding values extracted from a data structure is at the very core of the concept** and hence the most common use case*".

Ainda, [este artigo](https://gvanrossum.github.io/docs/PyPatternMatching.pdf) (que possui entre os seus autores [o próprio criador do Python](https://gvanrossum.github.io/)) cita que "*Pattern matching allows programs both to **extract specific
information** from complex data types, as well as to branch
on the structure of data and thus apply specialized actions
to different forms of data*".

Ou seja, a ideia do *pattern matching* é a extração de valores baseados em algum padrão. O fato de *poder* ser usado de forma similar a um `switch` (ou a uma cadeia de `if`/`else`) é circunstancial. Mas vamos aos detalhes...

---

A especificação do *pattern matching* está na [PEP 634](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/), a motivação para criá-lo está na [PEP 635](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/) e um tutorial completo pode ser visto na [PEP 636](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/), então só vou apontar algumas linhas mais gerais, para dar uma noção do que é.

A primeira diferença para o `switch` é que no `match` não há o [*fall through*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188461/switch-statement-fall-through-should-it-be-allowed): uma vez que ele entra em uma opção, as demais são ignoradas.

Ou seja, o código abaixo só imprime "Not found":

```
status = 404

match status:
    case 400:
        print("Bad request")
    case 404:
        print("Not found")
    case 418:
        print("I'm a teapot")
    case _:
        print("Something's wrong with the Internet")
```

Mas em linguagens que possuem `switch` (como JavaScript), caso não haja um `break` dentro de cada `case`, ocorre o *fall through*:

```js
var st = 404;

switch (st) {
  case 400:
    console.log('Bad request');
  case 404:
    console.log('Not found');
  case 418:
    console.log("I'm a teapot");
  default:
    console.log("Something's wrong with the Internet");
}
```

O código acima imprime:

```
Not found
I'm a teapot
Something's wrong with the Internet
```

Para que ele imprima apenas "Not found", é necessário ter um `break` dentro de cada `case`.

Então a primeira diferença é que o `match` não precisa desse `break`. Mas tem muito mais...

---

No [link já citado](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636) tem todos os exemplos completos, mas para dar uma resumida, juntei vários em um só. Nos exemplos é usado um caso em que o usuário digita um comando e o `match` analisa o que foi digitado para tomar uma ação:

```
command = input('command: ')

match command.split():
    case ["quit"]:
        print("Goodbye!")
        quit_game()
    case ["look"]:
        current_room.describe()
    case ["get", obj] | ["pick", "up", obj] | ["pick", obj, "up"]:
        character.get(obj, current_room)
    case ["go", direction] if direction in current_room.exits:
        current_room = current_room.neighbor(direction)
    case ["go", _]:
        print("Sorry, you can't go that way")
    case ["drop", *objects]:
        for obj in objects:
            do_something(obj)
    case _:
        print('invalid command')
```

Nos 2 primeiros casos (`case ["quit"]` e `case ["look"]`), há o *pattern matching* para valores específicos. Ou seja, se a string digitada for exatamente "quit" ou "look", ele cai no respectivo `case` (lembrando que `split` retorna uma lista, por isso o `case` foi feito com uma lista contendo a string).

Depois vemos outro caso: `case ["get", obj] | ["pick", "up", obj] | ["pick", obj, "up"]`. Aqui temos o `|`, que indica "ou" - quer dizer que há 3 opções diferentes que podem cair neste `case`. Ou é uma lista contendo a string "get" e alguma outra string (cujo valor será colocado na variável `obj`), ou é uma lista com 3 strings, contendo "pick", "up" e alguma outra string (que será `obj`), sendo que nas opções a ordem varia (ou seja, eu poderia digitar "pick up objeto" ou "pick objeto up").

A seguir temos a opção de adicionar um *guard* ao `case`:

```
case ["go", direction] if direction in current_room.exits:
    current_room = current_room.neighbor(direction)
case ["go", _]:
    print("Sorry, you can't go that way")
```

Ou seja, se foi encontrado um *match* no `case ["go", direction]`, a condição é avaliada (no caso, verifico se o valor de `direction` é um dos que eu considero válidos). Se for, ele entra no `case`, caso contrário, ele entra no `case` de baixo.

Por fim, temos o caso em que é usado o *unpacking*: `case ["drop", *objects]`. Ou seja, se for digitado "drop obj1 obj2 obj3", os valores "obj1", "obj2" e "obj3" estarão na lista `objects` (se digitar apenas "drop", a lista `objects` estará vazia).

---

Existe ainda a possibilidade de se fazer o *matching* na estrutura de um dicionário:

```
dados = {"text": "Lorem ipsum", "color": "azul"}

match dados:
    case { "text": texto, "color": cor }: # cai neste case
        print(f'imprimir "{texto}" na cor {cor}')
    case { "sound": arquivo, "format": formato }:
        print(f'Tocando {arquivo} (formato: {formato})')
```

Assim, eu posso verificar se o dicionário possui determinadas chaves e já atribuir os valores em variáveis. No exemplo acima, como o dicionário tem as chaves "text" e "color", as variáveis `texto` e `cor` terão os respectivos valores.

Vale lembrar que o dicionário pode ter outras chaves além das indicadas, e que o *matching* é feito na ordem em que os `case`'s estão, entrando no primeiro que for encontrado. Por exemplo, no caso abaixo, ele entra no primeiro `case` (mesmo que ele tenha as chaves que também dariam *match* no segundo `case`):

```
dados = { "sound": "musica", "format": "mp3", "text": "Lorem ipsum", "color": "azul"}
match dados:
    case { "text": texto, "color": cor }: # entra neste case
        print(f'imprimir "{texto}" na cor {cor}')
    case { "sound": arquivo, "format": formato }:
        print(f'Tocando {arquivo} (formato: {formato})')
```

Mas se eu invertesse a ordem dos `case`'s, ele encontraria primeiro as chaves "sound" e "format":

```
dados = { "sound": "musica", "format": "mp3", "text": "Lorem ipsum", "color": "azul"}
match dados:
    case { "sound": arquivo, "format": formato }: # entra neste case
        print(f'Tocando {arquivo} (formato: {formato})')
    case { "text": texto, "color": cor }:
        print(f'imprimir "{texto}" na cor {cor}')
```

E ainda existe a possibilidade de verificar os tipos dos valores:

```
dados = { "nome": "Fulano de tal", "idade": 30 }
match dados:
    case { "nome": str(nome), "idade": int(idade) }:
        print(f'{nome} tem {idade} anos')
    case _:
        print('matching not found')
```

Ou seja, somente se `nome` for uma string e `idade` for um inteiro, dará *match* no primeiro `case` (por exemplo, se eu mudasse o valor da idade para a string `"30"`, não funcionaria, e ele entraria no segundo `case`).

E se quiser obter as chaves restantes (caso o dicionário tenha chaves a mais), basta usar um *wildcard*:

```
dados = { "nome": "Fulano de tal", "idade": 30, "email": "fulano@email.com", "filhos": 2 }
match dados:
    case { "nome": str(nome), "idade": int(idade), **resto }:
        print(f'{nome} tem {idade} anos', resto)
```

No exemplo acima, `resto` será um dicionário contendo as chaves restantes ("email" e "filhos") e seus respectivos valores.

---

Enfim, como pode ver, é bem mais que um simples `switch`, pois além de analisar o valor, o `match` também pode avaliar a estrutura interna, inclusive com classes, conforme os exemplos abaixo:

```
# obviamente, assumindo que as classes Click, KeyPress e Quit existem
match event.get():
    case Click(position=(x, y)):
        handle_click_at(x, y)
    case KeyPress(key_name="Q") | Quit():
        game.quit()
    case KeyPress(key_name="up arrow"):
        game.go_north()
```

Ou seja, seria possível não só verificar se o evento é uma instância de determinada classe, como ainda obter os valores de seus atributos diretamente.

---

Um outro detalhe é que, diferente de outras linguagens ([como por exemplo Rust, citado nos comentários](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html#matches-are-exhaustive)), o `match` não é exaustivo. Ou seja, não precisamos testar todas as possibilidades nos `case`'s.

Portanto, o exemplo da pergunta poderia não ter a cláusula *default*:

```
status = 444
match status:
    case 400:
        print("Bad request")
    case 404:
        print("Not found")
    case 418:
        print("I'm a teapot")
```

Neste caso, o código acima não imprime nada, pois nenhum dos `case`'s encontra um *match*.

---

E apenas para terminar, outra diferença para o `switch` é que em muitas linguagens a cláusula *default* não precisa necessariamente ser a última. Por exemplo, em JavaScript, o código abaixo imprime "Something's wrong with the Internet":

```js
var st = 444;
switch(st) {
    case 400:
        console.log("Bad request");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Something's wrong with the Internet");
        break;
    case 404:
        console.log("Not found");
        break;
    case 418:
        console.log("I'm a teapot");
        break;
}
```

Mas no `match` do Python, isso dá erro:

```
status = 444
match status:
    case 400:
        print("Bad request")
    case _: # erro, cláusula "default" deve ser a última
        print("Something's wrong with the Internet")
    case 404:
        print("Not found")
    case 418:
        print("I'm a teapot")
```

No caso, o `case _` deve ser o último.

---

Enfim, em linhas gerais, é isso. Para todos os detalhes, leia as PEP's já listadas no início.

Comment: Sensacional. Saberia dizer se existe alguma similaridade com `match` do rust?

Comment: @Lucas Infelizmente não conheço Rust o suficiente pra poder responder...

Comment: @Lucas, na essência é quase a mesma coisa. No entanto, como o `match` do Python é uma declaração, não tem a obrigatoriedade de ser exaustivo, já que não precisa "retornar um valor" na avaliação. Já o _pattern match_ do Rust, como é uma _expressão_, sempre deve retornar um valor, o que implica na necessidade de sempre ser [exaustivo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html#matches-are-exhaustive).

Comment: Eu gostaria de deixar três exemplos de implementação que levam o pattern match a outro nível: [LISP](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Pattern_002dMatching-Conditional.html), [Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) e [Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html). Eu pessoalmente gostaria que Python se seguisse, pelo menos mirasse, um desses exemplos.

Answer (score 8):

Eu acompanhei desde a primeira proposta e as várias interações do desenvolvimento até a proposta final que está sendo implementada.

> Como funciona o match em Python?

A ideia do match é, a partir de um objeto, ou resultado de uma expressão
você executar um trecho de código que vai poder extrair valores e normalizar
variáveis para serem consumidos mais abaixo do código.

Para isso, há dois recursos: as patterns em si, que permitem a
associação de variáveis já no momento da comparação, no comando
`case`, e, quando elas não forem suficientes, no bloco do `case`,
qualquer trecho de código de Python válido.

Fora isso, por conta dessa estrutura, em que os comandos
`case` permitem um trecho de código sempre que o padrão casar,
os comandos `match/case` também funcionam como o `switch/case` do
C - mas isso é um "bônus", uma vez que a execução condicional de blocos
de código como acontece no switch/case já é plenamente atendida
pelo `if/elif/else` em Python, como exemplifiquei na resposta [que você
ligou à pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127104/iterar-um-lista-dentro-de-switch).

> É exaustivo? O que ocorre se o valor a ser consultado não dê match em
> nenhum braço?

O mesmo que em um `if/elif` que não entrasse em nenhum bloco: em tempo
de execução: nada - simplesmente o programa continua a execução na primeira
linha depois do bloco do `match`. No entanto, a recomendação para ferramentas
de análise estática de código (como Pyflakes, mypi, etc...) é dar pelo menos
um warning nesses casos.

Lembrando que a análise estática de código é um passo opcional para desenvolvedores Python para localizar erros e "coisas estranhas" que linguagens
estáticas acham em tempo de compilação. Os mesmos erros só aconteceriam em Python em tempo de execução, por ser uma linguagem dinâmica.

> Ele permite o desempacotamento de valores?

Sim -  e essa é a justificativa principal para a inclusão da nova sintaxe. O "desempacotamento de valores", ou "desconstrução de objetos".

Então, um dos maiores exemplos que vem ao longo das PEPs que descreveram a funcionalidade, seria uma função que iria fazer uma operação com as coordenadas
"x" e "y"  de um ponto geométrico - só que ela pode receber esse ponto de várias formas diferentes: ele pode ser passado como uma tupla de dois valores, como um
dicionário com as chaves "x" e "y", ou como um objeto do tipo "Point" que tenha os atributos "x" e "y". A estrutura match/case permite um trecho de código mais elegante que uma série de if/elifs para garantir que esses valores estejam
nas variáveis `x` e `y` para o restante do código:

```py
def distance(point):
    match point:
        case Point(x, y): 
            pass
        case [x, y]:
            pass
        case {"x":x, "y": y}:
            pass
        case _:
            raise TypeError("Não foi possível reconhecer as coordenadas")
    return math.hypot(x, y)
```

E no terminal, com uma versão de dev do Python 3.10 funciona assim:

```py
In [6]: from dataclasses import dataclass

In [7]: @dataclass
   ...: class Point:
   ...:     x: float
   ...:     y: float
   ...: 

In [8]: distance([3,4])
Out[8]: 5.0

In [9]: distance(Point(3, 4))
Out[9]: 5.0

In [10]: distance({"x":3, "y":4})
Out[10]: 5.0
```

Como você pode ver, o ponto principal é que dentro da cláusula `case` se usa uma sintaxe nova, onde variáveis "soltas" recebem os valores dos padrões que casam
(no caso do `Point` com os atributos em sequência usados na construção do Point,
mas tem como ser outro nome também), na segunda cláusula, qualquer sequência de comprimento 2, e na terceira, qualquer objeto "mapping" (objetos que funcionam coo um dicionário) que tenha as chaves "x" e "y" - e na quarta cláusula o "default").
Nesse caso, não foi necessário nenhum código dentro dos blocos `match` - o valor
desejado já estava desconstruído para as variáveis x e y - (o comando `pass`
inclusive poderia estar na mesma linha)

> Historicamente, o switch não existe em Python, mas agora é possível
> dizer que essa estrutura consta na linguagem? Ou são coisas
> diferentes?

Como escrevi no primeiro parágrafo: a funcionalidade do "switch" acaba
entrando como "bônus" na linguagem com o "match/case" - mas é quase que
uma segunda forma de fazer a mesma coisa - com alguma expressividade a mais
permitida pela sintaxe da expressão do `match` (ou seja, expressões
"match" poderão ficar mais curtas e legíveis do que as mesmas expressões usando
"if" - ao custo de ter que se entender uma nova sintaxe)

Comment: "*qualquer sequência de comprimento 2*" - interessante, eu achei que o `case [x, y]` daria *match* somente com listas, mas fiz o teste aqui passando uma tupla e um `range(3, 5)` e ambos funcionaram. Então isso funcionaria com qualquer iterador/iterável?

Comment: iterador não - pq. iterador não tem `len` (método `__len__`). Qualquer sequência sim - o range é um objeto que é mais que um iterador: ele tem `len`.

Comment: É mesmo, testei com uma generator function e não foi (pois não tem `len`)... Mudando de assunto, vc sabe por que preferiram `case _` em vez de `default` (ou então `else`, ou qualquer outra opção)?

Comment: Vou aproveitar e perguntar se você também sabe porque eles optaram por fazer o `match` uma declaração, e não uma expressão, conforme parece ser mais comum entre o _pattern match_ em outras linguagens.

Comment: Depois da primeira proposta, escrita por 5 ou 6 autores, incluindo o Guido, foram trocados centenas de e-mails públicos, pedindo e argumentado a favor de todas as formas e possibilidades possíveis. Nessa fase, houve pedidos para ser uma expressão - mas não vou lembrar por que se convencionou que a forma com comandos era melhor. Acho que por no fim, prover mais flexibilidade: com os blocos `case` você pode complementar com qualquer código extra que precisar - portanto  tem mais possibilidades de uso.

Comment: Quanto a por que não usaram  `default` ou `else` : foram dezenas de e-mails pedindo outra forma, e não vou lembrar a argumentação em favor do `case _:`.  Eu preferiria `else` também, já que é usado em tantos outros comandos em Python.